# Installed via pip, can't import tensorflow on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I installed tensorflow on my RPi 3B+ using:

```
pip3 install tensorflow --user
```

When I launch the python interpreter on the command line, and do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It gives me an error:
    ImportError: No module named tensorflow

If I do `pip3 show tensorflow`, it tells me that Tensorflow is installed:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.11.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: termcolor, keras-preprocessing, six, grpcio, tensorboard, absl-py, numpy, gast, setuptools, protobuf, astor, keras-applications, wheel
Required-by:
```

I don't understand why python3 cannot import tensorflow if it is installed at site-packages

Comment: Are you running your script with python3? please provide a minimal reproduction listing the commands you executed.

Comment: Yes it's python3, 
I don't have a script. I am planning to make a Face Recog model on the RPi, for which I need tensorflow. 
When I install it via pip3, it installs successfully. When I import it on the python terminal, it gives me a Module Not Found

Comment: Are you sure you are starting `python3`? Please provide a full listing of the commands you are running, including the results.
Raspbian also has Python2 installed, and when you run `python` on the commandline, you're getting Python2.

Comment: Also, this document might help: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip